# Elegant way of checking list containment using Java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this list `myList` of `MyObj` class which contains an `String id` field.

I am provided with two id's `(String)` from the user, and want to validate that `myList`
contains two instances of `MyObj` corresponding to these provided id's.

What's an elegant way of doing so using `streams`?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
boolean contains = myList.stream()
                         .map(MyObj::getID)
                         .filter(id -> id.equals(id1) || id.equals(id2))
                         .limit(2)
                         .count () == 2;
```

This is assuming there can be at most one `MyObj` having `id1` and at most one `MyObj` having `id2`, which makes sense if these identifiers are unique.

I added the `limit(2)` in order for the pipeline to stop processing elements once it finds two elements matching the requested identifiers.